# LINQ Distinct set by column value

Tags: linq

Is there a simple LINQ query to get distinct records by a specific column value (not the whole record)?

Anyone know how i can filter a list with only distinct values?

Comment: Do you want just to return just the distinct column, or other values too?

Answer (score 3):

You could use libraries like [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) to do this.  You'd be interested in the `DistinctBy()` method.

```
var query = records.DistinctBy(record => record.Column);
```

Otherwise, you could do this by hand.

```
var query =
    from record in records
    group record by record.Column into g
    select g.First();
```

Comment: how to add order by in the second query?

Answer (score 2):

Select a single value first and then run the Distinct.

```
 (from item in table
 select item.TheSingleValue).Distinct();
```

If you want the entire record you need to use `group x by into y`. You then need to find a suitable aggregate function like `First`, `Max`, `Average` or similar to select one of the other values in the group.

```
from item in table
group item by item.TheSingleValue into g
select new { TheSingleValue = g.Key, OtherValue1 = g.First().OtherValue1, OtherValue2 = g.First().OtherValue2 };
```

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants the entire records to be returned though, not just the items

Answer (score 0):

You could make an implementation of the IEqualityComparer interface:

```
public class MyObjectComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyObject>
{
    public bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        return x.ColumnNameProperty == y.ColumnNameProperty;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(MyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.ColumnNameProperty.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And pass an instance into the Distinct method:

```
var distinctSource = source.Distinct(new MyObjectComparer());
```